# Only 1 collection shown to non-admin users. Other collections they have access to are hidden

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm running Azure DevOps Server 2019 RC1 with multiple collections at https://myurl.com/ and most things are working great but there is one small issue.

I, as an Admin, can see all of my collections listed down the left hand side.  But non-admin users are only seeing 1 collection.  Even though they have access to projects on multiple collections, when they connect to https://myurl.com they are directed to https://myurl.com/Collection1/ and only Collection1 is shown in the collection selection pane on left hand side..

If they manually enter https://myurl.com/Collection2/ then they are able to see Collection2 projects and Collection2 is shown on the left hand side, but Collection1 is no longer displayed in collection selection.

The same is true if they manually go to https://myurl.com/Collection3/, only Collection3 is shown.  I on the other hand can see Collection1, Collection2, Collection3, Collection4 etc.

How can the user discover collections they have access to without being given a direct link?

Thanks

Comment: Have you reported it to Microsoft? It sounds like a bug.

Comment: @DanielMann No, not yet.  I'm asking here first incase there is some element of user error.  Perhaps some new permission I haven't found to make a collection visible.  It certainly could be a bug.

Comment: It has been reported as a bug, no resolution or work arounds as of yet: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/403717/non-admin-users-cannot-see-list-of-collections-in.html